# Is it possible to use TimeSeriesGenerator to fit a Functional Model with two inputs in Keras, Tensorflow 2?

Tags: keras, time-series, generator, lstm, tensorflow2.0

For a concrete example here is some code:

```
input1 = Input(shape = (3,2))
x1 = LSTM(8)(input1)
x1 = Flatten()(x1)
x1 = Dense(10)(x1)


input2 = Input(shape = (3,2))
x2 = LSTM(8)(input2)
x2 = Flatten()(x2)
x2 = Dense(10)(x2)

x = concatenate([x1, x2])

y = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model([input1, input2], y)

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Is it possible to use a Keras generator to fit this model with two numpy arrays?

E.g.

```
X1 = np.random.randn((100, 2))
X2 = np.random.randn((100, 2))
```